# Get Words from database - There will be no content out

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

This is how I have tried to do so that it retrieves my content in the database. I get content rather by doing it through C # but I want to make so that it finds words instantly while writing "L" then comes all words forward with L in itself.

Now comes the not the content at all. But I reload the page quick gives me a kind of sign to {{VALUE}} exists but get nothing down.

**There is no error in Colsole**

Words.cshtml

```
<div class="container" style="min-height:300px;" ng-app="WordSpreads" ng-controller="WordSpreadsListValue">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" placeholder="@Helpers.HelperText.ContentPanel.WordText" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="test">
    <div ng-repeat="Value in entries | filter:test"> 
        {{ Value }}
    </div>
</div>
```

LoadWords.js:

```
var app = angular.module('WordSpreads', []);
app.controller('WordSpreadsListValue', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('../Profile/MWordSpreads').success(function(data){
        $scope.entries = data.entries;
    });
});
```

Profile:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MWordSpreads()
    {
        WordsSpreadsListValue model = new WordsSpreadsListValue();

        var db = HelperToTables.DbValue;
        model.List = db.WordSpreads.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

I look for here:

1. [Her](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input)
2. [Http-Get](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_get)

EIDT - Update :

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult MWordSpreads()
    {
        WordsSpreadsListValue model = new WordsSpreadsListValue();

        var db = HelperToTables.DbValue;
        var _modelList = db.WordSpreads.ToList();

        return Json(_modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested only the client part (Javascript) and it worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="min-height:300px;" ng-app="WordSpreads" ng-controller="WordSpreadsListValue">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="test">
    <div ng-repeat="Value in entries | filter:test"> 
        {{ Value }}
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('WordSpreads', []);
app.controller('WordSpreadsListValue', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.entries = [
        'Astrid',
        'Bjarne',
        'Casper',
        'Erik',
        'Kristin',
        'Lisbet',
        'Mikael',
        'Peter',
        'Pia',
        'Thomas'
    ];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This helps you?

...

Ah! prefer to use

```
$http.get('../Profile/MWordSpreads')
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.entries = response.data.entries;
}, function(rejection) {
    alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(rejection, null, 4));
});
```

instead of

```
$http.get('../Profile/MWordSpreads')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.entries = data.entries;
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('Error: ' + status +  ' ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `../Profile/MWordSpreads`,it returns a html document as data and set to `$scope.entries`. That's why you won't get data displayed in page.

I suggest use ApiController instead.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public WordsSpreadsListValue MWordSpreads()
    {
        WordsSpreadsListValue model = new WordsSpreadsListValue();

        var db = HelperToTables.DbValue;
        model.List = db.WordSpreads.ToList();

        return model;
     }
```

Long time not use angularjs, I'm not sure if codes below works.

LoadWords.js:
`$scope.entries = data.List;`

Words.cshtml: you could get property of class `WordSpreads` like this `{{Value.someprop}}`

Comment: I can see your thoughts about it. but it is such that it does not come forward with proposals / it as I have written in the database.

Comment: I can also tell you that it makes mistakes when you do it that way when I came to the site. So it does not exactly what you write.

Comment: Typically, you just need to return data to front-end. I'm using webapi2,so I change return to model. Of course you can return jsonresult, serialize model and return to front-end.

Comment: Yes I have also read me until tonight. I have tried my way of doing so here for example. I added up my updater.